# C# - Get Most recently created File name

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get most recently created file name from a directory. I tried below thing.

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Result");
    var file = dirInfo.GetFiles("PaperResult*").Select(f => f.CreationTime).First();
    Console.WriteLine(file);
```

But it is returning me Date and Time. It is not returning the file name. What am I missing here ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to order-by `CreationTime`, you don't want to select it.

```
var file = dirInfo.GetFiles("PaperResult*")
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).First();
```

Comment: Great...I just wanted this. Thanks Tim .

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the MoreLinq Library `MaxBy(..)` method (MoreLinq available on Nuget, or here
https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
var file = dirInfo.GetFiles("PaperResult*").MaxBy(f=> f.CreationTime);
```

This library has many other useful extensions, well worth getting hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = dirInfo.GetFiles("PaperResult*").OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).First();
Console.WriteLine(file);
```

Comment: This is exactly what Tim posted except you added a write line that will display the object file.